# Como excluir um campo/propriedade de um record para que não use no método de igualdade o de hash?

Tags: c#, .net, atributos, record-types

Por exemplo, neste registro eu usei um atributo, que não existe, para que o campo `Endereco` não seja usado para `Equals()`, `GetHashCode()`, e até outros métodos, como o `ToString()`.

```
public record Cliente {
    public string Nome;
    public string Cpf;
    [NoIdentity] public string Endereco;
}
```

Tem outro atributo que faz isso? Ou tem outra forma?

Comment: Pod ser só um negativo pontual, ou pode ser que a pessoa tenha um motivo para negativar isso. Poderia me dizer para que eu pessoa fazer algo a respeito e aprender o que está errado. Se a mesma pessoa vota em tudo o que eu posto consistentemente ela precisa ter uma motivo para não caracterizar perseguição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe um atributo, nem outra técnica, a não ser você implementar quaisquer desses métodos, provavelmente todos eles, na mão e escolhendo como vai proceder e quais campos vai usar.

Não se esqueça que a implementação fornecida pelo `record` não é obrigatória.

Por outro lado, sem usar a implementação padrão o uso de `record` perde muito do sentido. Se precisa fazer isso talvez seja um indicativo que ele não é a melhor ferramenta para o caso que está trabalhando. Não parece que seja uma falha não ter e que será sanado no futuro, é intencional ser assim para que o `record` não seja abusado.

[Alguém já tentou algo menos ambicioso](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3925), até faria um pouco mais sentido. Lá sugeriram criar um gerador de código próprio para alcançar o objetivo.